# PHP Regular Expression Using Apostrophe Failing

Tags: php, regex

To start off, I don't use regular expressions very often so I figured I would throw this out here.

I've got a regular expression I am using to find any special characters except the ones that I would like to allow.

```
$allowed_special_characters_list = array('-', "'", '.');
$excluded_special_characters = '';

foreach($allowed_special_characters_list as $excluded_special_character){
    $excluded_special_characters .= "\\".$excluded_special_character;
}

if(preg_match("/[^\\w".$excluded_special_characters."\\s]/", $string)){
    return true;
}
```

When I output this regular expression it gives me the following:

```
/[^\w\-\'\.\s]/
```

This seems to be working for everything except the apostrophe in my environment. However, when I put this exact regular expression in [PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/), it seems to work with everything.

Any ideas as to what's wrong with this?

Edit: The code above is a simplified version of what I am actually using. I am dynamically building this regex from an array that is in a configuration file. Anytime we need to add another special character, we will only need to input it into the array.

Comment: It is working for me `var_dump(preg_match('/[^\w\-\'\.\s]/', "b&z"));` return `int(1)` and `var_dump(preg_match('/[^\w\-\'\.\s]/', "a'b"));` return `int(0)`. You are searching for `not a word char, and not minus, and not apostrophe, and not dot, and not  whitechar`. Btw you don't need to escape `.` character inside character class and you can use `preg_quote()` for automatic escaping.

Answer (score 2):

The logic above does, in fact, work. The issue had to do with the data in the $string variable in the preg_match. I had to add **html_entity_decode($NameAndAddressData, ENT_QUOTES)** when setting the name and address variables.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable issue with your regex is that you mix allowed and disallowed characters inside 1 regex.

You exclude all alphanumerics with `[^\w]`, it is not a special character. Also, check out if you also need to allow multiple words since you have `\s` inside the excluded character class. And the most important thing is that you have a negated character class of size 1, which means only 1 character will be checked in the whole string for a match, and I suspect you need to check if all the characters do not belong to the excluded class.

So, the regex you need is something like `^[^\-\'\.\s]*$` (that will disallow multiple words, leading/trailing spaces), and the code to check if a word is validated is:

```
$string = 'My bad string';
$string2 = 'Goodstring';
$re = "/^[^".$excluded_special_characters."\\s]*$/";
if(!preg_match($re, $string)){
    echo "false 1\n";
}
if(preg_match($re, $string2)){
    echo "true 2\n";
}
```

Output:

```
false 1 ('My bad string' has spaces)
true 2  ('Goodstring' is OK)
```

Comment: I am excluding alphanumeric characters and allowing multiple words on purpose. This regular expression looks at names and addresses to see if any invalid characters exist.

There are two arrays of allowed special characters. One for names and one for addresses. The regular expression is built to be dynamic to account for each special character defined in each array.

To the point of the negated class size of 1, with what I have just described, do you feel as if that is correct seeing that the purpose is to see if the string has any special characters **except** the ones defined in the arrays?

Comment: With my comment above, what do you suggest the regular expression look like? Thanks for your help by the way. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Note that by "special character" you mean something different from `\p{S}`. Now, to check if there are any other non- `[a-zA-Z_]`s, digits, (white)space, and $excluded_special_characters, there is no problem with your regex: `/[^\w\-\'\.\s]/`. Problems might be with the input: apostrophes may be curly, Japanese, etc.